# VS2008 web site references

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference

I have a web site project in vs2008.  When you add a reference to a dll, it simply copies the dll into the bin directory.  I do not like to check in the bin directory into version control.  Any ideas on how to make the reference work without converting to a web application (I'm just doing maintenance on an existing site).

Answer (score 2):

One solution, if I understand correctly is:

Create a support folder for the DLLs you wish to reference in your project (we use _support here so that is goes to the top of the tree) in the solution folder.

> Solution
>
> ..._support
>   ...WebProject

Copy the DLL's into here and then reference the DLL from this directory, this is a nicer solution then checking in the bin.

Comment: I have a directory that contains the dlls.  But I have to add the reference if I delete the bin directory.

Comment: So to confirm your situation, you have a folder above the project folder with your DLLs in and you then add a reference in VS. When you've added the reference, what is the path of the reference in the properties window?